# Two ways ANOVA does not show the interaction between the variables

Tags: r, anova, interaction, two-way

I am doing a two-way ANOVA and I want to examine the interaction between two variables. The variables are the following: STS (Sign language knowledge) and Hearing (if they are hearing or deaf). Both variables are binary (0 or 1). I want to examine if any of them shows an effect to their spelling errors in their writing. So I have coded this:

```
spellingerrors <- aov(moasdata$Spelling.errors ~ STS* Hearing + STS:Hearing, data = moasdata)
summary(spellingerrors)
```

I got this in my console:

```
           Df   Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
STS          1 0.000202 0.0002020   0.267 0.6093  
Hearing      1 0.002366 0.0023661   3.132 0.0881 .
Residuals   27 0.020399 0.0007555
```

I expected that "STS:Hearing" would show the between-interaction, but it does not appear in the console.

So I tried with another similar variable, by using the variable SignRep that is non-binary (SignRep is a Sign Language test with a point scale between 0.0 and 4.0 points) as variable instead for STS. I coded this:

```
spellingerrors2 <- aov(moasdata$Spelling.errors ~ Signrep* Hearing + Signrep:Hearing, data = moasdata)
summary(spellingerrors2)
```

And then I could see the interaction between SignRep and Hearing.

```
                         Df   Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
moasdata$Signrep          1 0.000273 0.0002728   0.348 0.5603  
Hearing                   1 0.002305 0.0023050   2.942 0.0982 .
moasdata$Signrep:Hearing  1 0.000017 0.0000169   0.022 0.8842  
Residuals                26 0.020372 0.0007835
```

I would prefer to use the binary variable STS rather than SignRep. I have tried to convert STS (and hearing) both as factors, and as numerics (SignRep is numeric), but it does not help at all.

Why does it not work?

Best,
Moa

Comment: This is purely an R question, for which SO is probably a better option. (A*B is Wilkinson's notation for experimental design, and it expands to A + B + A:B, so you don't have to put your interaction term twice.)

Comment: Do all 4 combinations of STS and Hearing occur? I would not be surprised if all not Hearing had STS.

Comment: You will probably need to post your data or some good summaries / descriptions of it, to get any answers, and SO would be a better place.